# how to add live clock in DIVI wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i m curious, is there anything we can do to add live clock at DIVI wordpress? i trying use javascript, but i can add live clock at wordpress.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and `setInterval` to show new time every second.

```js
setInterval(function () {
  var time = new Date();
  
  var placeholder = document.getElementById('time');
  
  placeholder.innerHTML = time.getHours()+':'+time.getMinutes()+':'+time.getSeconds();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: well i don't know where i can put this code in DIVI wordpress @Justinas

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could also use plugins:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/live-clock-date/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/local-time-clock/